# Highest Polarity Score (Sentiment Analysis) using the TextBlob library

Tags: python, textblob

I've started to use the TextBlob library; for sentiment analysis. 
I have run a few tests on a few phrases and I have the polarity and subjectivity score - fine.

What sentence would return the highest *polarity* value within TextBlob?

For instance

"I really, really, really love and admire your beauty, my good friend"

returns a polarity score of 0.6.

I understand that +1.0 is the highest score (-1.0) is the least.

What sentence, have you found which returns a score closer to +1.0?

> > > TextBlob("I really, really, really love and admire your beauty my good friend").sentiment
> > >       Sentiment(*polarity=0.6*, subjectivity=0.6000000000000001)
> > >
> > > TextBlob("I really, really, really love my place of work").sentiment 
> > >       Sentiment(*polarity=0.5*, subjectivity=0.6)
> > >
> > > TextBlob("I really love my place of work").sentiment
> > >       Sentiment(*polarity=0.5*, subjectivity=0.6)

---

I expect that the "really" should increase the sentiment score, at least a bit.  (i.e. really, really like = at least 0.9)

I expect that the score overall, without the really (I really like my work) should return a score closer to 1.0.

Comment: Hooray! I noticed that "I am very happy" returns a sentiment score 1.0.

Comment: >>> TextBlob("I am very happy").sentiment
Sentiment(polarity=1.0, subjectivity=1.0)

Comment: If anyone wants to add any comments to how TextBlob classifies it's sentences into positive/negative do add them. I still believe "I really, really, really love and admire your beauty, my good friend" should return a higher sentiment score.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.sentiment_assessments` to get some more idea of how your sentence is being evaluated.

Sentiment(polarity=0.6, subjectivity=0.6000000000000001, assessments=[(['really', 'really', 'really', 'love'], 0.5, 0.6, None), (['good'], 0.7, 0.6000000000000001, None)])